# Can learning a new language help with speech impairment?

Tags: language-change, language-acquisition

I'm not a linguist, but i can see the connection between speech impairment and language learning.

I'm only asking because I have a slight speech impairment myself (unable to pronounce guttural sounds like Guh, or Tuh, also 's' sounds like 'sushi'  or 'sausage'). This is due to physical constraints/left side face paralysis due to surgery I have had in the past. Although as I age I have become increasingly more aware of this which has helped i guess.

I have been to a speech therapist before without much luck, I was young and through my naivety found saying the same stupid phrase over and over again, a drag (and still do :P). They said my hearing has become attuned to thinking I sound normal. I was thinking lately however about learning a new language but i am concerned that i might end up learning it incorrectly. Will it be more beneficial to try and sort out my english first (if i can) or see if i can push the reset button on a new language?

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics.SE! The topic of this site is studying the linguistic phenomenons itself, not the process of language acquisition in relation to speech impairment. However, two other Stack Exchange sites come to my mind: [languagelearning.se] and [health.se]. Please look around there and decide which one suits best for asking this question.